# jQuery fade in and animate at the same time on document ready

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, jquery-animate

I have a modal popup that I'm trying to get to fade in and animate at the same time when the document is ready but I can't get it to function. I can fadeIn just fine:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".modal").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

But I can't get it to both fade in and animate. I have tried

```
$('.modal').animate({ opacity: 1, top: "-10px" }, 'slow');
```

But this doesn't work for me either. And advice would be appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to help without seeing some HTML mockup of the popup. Can you provide more information?

Comment: Call both methods: `$(".modal").fadeIn("slow").animate({ opacity: 1, top: "-10px" }, 'slow')`

Comment: Thanks Rory, but that code fades in THEN animates. It doesn't do both at the same time.

Comment: Tomas - the modal html is just this: <div class="modal"><a href="#" class="close-modal"></a>Some content</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use opacity animation:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.modal').css('display', 'block'); //if you have display: none on the element
 $('.modal').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 0);
    $('.modal').animate({ opacity: 1, top: "-10px" }, 'slow');
});
```

```css
.modal {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal">Some content</div>
```